# Probability of extinction in generation 3

Tags: probability, markov-chains, conditional-probability

The branching process has offspring distribution $μ(0) = a, μ(1) = b, μ(2) = c$ and $μ(n) = 0$, what is the probability that the population is extinct in the 3rd generation, given that it is not extinct in the 2nd generation?

How would i solve this? How is it different from finding the probability of extinction in exactly generation 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $X_n$ is the event of extinction in exactly generation $n$

then the probability of extinction in generation $3$ is $\mathbb P(X_3)$

but the probability of extinction in generation $3$ given not extinct *by* generation $2$ (i.e. no extinction *in* generation $1$ or *in* generation $2$) is $$\mathbb P(X_3 \mid X_1^c, X_2^c) = \dfrac{\mathbb P(X_3 ,X_1^c, X_2^c)}{\mathbb P(X_1^c, X_2^c)}\text{ which is }\dfrac{\mathbb P(X_3 )}{1-\big(\mathbb P(X_1)+\mathbb P(X_2)\big)}$$ since $X_3 \subset X_1^c \cap X_2^c$ and $X_1 \cap X_2 = \emptyset$

Comment: Thanks so much, this makes a lot of sense! when finding P(X2) would I be using the probability that the population is extinct by generation 2 or the probability that the population is extinct in exactly generation 2?

Comment: @gooses08 That is a good point and means I need to change my answer slightly